# How to calculate page number of pages and page size for multilevel paging?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory, paging

I have the following virtual address:

```
+---------+----------+----------+
+ 7 Bit x | 13 Bit y | Offset d +
+---------+----------+----------+
```

I now have the following task:

```
1. Of how many pages consists the virtual address space?
2. What size has one page?
3. How much memory can be addressed by one entry in the page table?
4. To which page in which page table does the address 0xCF 4223 correspond in the virtual space?
```

I tried to solve the tasks like the follwing:

For the first one I just calculated $2^{13}=8192$ thus we have $8192$ pages in the address space.

For the second one I calculated this $$\text{size of pages}=\frac{\text{size address space}}{\text{amount of pages}}=\frac{2^{32}\text{ bit}}{2^{13}}=64\text{ kibibyte}$$

For the third one I calculated this $$\text{memory per entry}=\frac{\text{size address space}}{\text{amount of entries}}=\frac{2^{32}\text{ bit}}{2^{7}}=40\text{ mebibyte}$$

Can someone verify these solutions or explain how I can calculate it correctly if I did something wrong?

For the fourth task I don't really know what I have to do. I converted the hexadecimal address to a decimal address: $$(0\text{xCF}\:4223)_{16}=(13582899)_{10}$$ But I don't know how to progress from here.